# How to match two data frames using columns' names of the second dataframe and the value in two columns of the first dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, merge

Let's say df_1 is as follows:

```
col_1 | col_2 | col_3 | ...
12338 | MD   | ...
13438 | LG   | ...
62248 | SM   | ...
92338 | SI   | ...
32818 | SM   | ...
.
.
.
```

Also, here is df_2:

```
col_1 | MD | LG | SM | SI
12338 | 10 | 29 | 8  | 7
12339 | 15 | 26 | 18 | 17
13438 | 78 | 18 | 77 | 1670
.
.
.
```

The goal is to find the target value for each row in df_1 based on df_2 and col_1 and col_2.
For example, for the first row of df_1, the target value would be 10 because col_1 is 12338 and using MD column in df_2.

For the second row of df_2, the target value would be 18 because col_1 is 13438 and using LG column in df_2.

```
col_1 | col_2 | Target | col_3 | ...
12338 | MD    | 10     | ...
13438 | LG    | 18     | ...
.
.
.
```

I want to do the above process for a very large data frame.

I knew that I can do it using merge or even using some if conditions, but I am looking for a very efficient and novel way that is too fast. Any innovative ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check with `lookup`

```
df1['Target']=df2.set_index('col_1').lookup(df1.col_1, df1.col_2)
```